# Quote pseudo-elements don't align evenly within element padding

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've styled a `blockquote` to add opening and closing quotation marks via CSS pseudo-elements, but they don't evenly center horizontally within the element's padding, so the closing quotation mark usually appears further away from the text. In my project, they're distributed slightly differently, so it's also a little inconsistent. How can I fix/improve this?

```
<div class="big-quote">
  <blockquote>This is a styled quote.</blockquote>
</div>


.big-quote {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
.big-quote blockquote {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2.444444444em;
  font-style: italic;
}
.big-quote blockquote::before, .big-quote blockquote::after {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #adadad;
}
.big-quote blockquote::before {
  content: "\201C";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.big-quote blockquote::after {
  content: "\201D";
  right: 0;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  float: right;
```

}

Demo: https://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/bGerROL

Comment: How is the width of big-quote (or other containing element) set in real life? If it is wide both quote marks can be a long way from the actual text. And is the overlap of the opening quote mark with the text (as in your codepen) the effect you want for both quote marks?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the quote marks are getting misplaced - and that is due to the blockquote taking up too much width (ie not being confined to the width of its text) so the quotes can end up a long way from the actual text.

In this snippet I've made a couple of alterations - see comments in the code.

```css
.big-quote {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}
.big-quote blockquote {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 2.6em 0.5em 2.6em;/* increased to allow room for the quotes in the padding */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2.444444444em;
  font-style: italic;
  width: auto;/* added */
/* margin:0 auto 0 auto;  removed in favour of the flex as was not working with % widths */
  max-width:70%; /* added to leave room for the quotes. A calc would be good but was not allowed */
}
.big-quote blockquote::before, .big-quote blockquote::after {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #adadad;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.big-quote blockquote::before {
  content: "\201C";
  top: 0;
  left: -0.1em;
}
.big-quote blockquote::after {
  content: "\201D";
  right: 0.1em;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  }
  
/* This is just a reminder to do something for smaller devices as the big font sizes don't fit in */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .big-quote blockquote {
    font-size:1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="big-quote">
  <blockquote>This is a styled quote.</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this. I was hoping that the quotes would be centred in the `blockquote`'s padding or flush against the sides closest to the text. If I inspect your answer, that's true for the closing quote, but the opening is further away from the text. If I put your code in my project, Both quotes are far from the text (the opening is also further away) and the text isn't centred anymore. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, I guess that means something else in your project is setting something we use here. I’ll take a look at the alignment within the padding though as I realise now I just assumed a positioning.

Comment: Well, in my project, `.big-quote` is just contained in a `section` with page margins and then `main`.